# Query job properties from sql in databricks

Tags: databricks

Is there a way to query databricks job properties via sql?
I have the job_id and I want to lookup its name with sql interface.

I am specifically looking for a way to query via sql and not using a api calls or other methods.
I've tried information schema but I believe since it is ansi schema information, it is not containing the jobs aspect of databricks!

Comment: Please share more details like what you have tried thus far and a specific problem. There are several approaches to the general question posed: 

(1) Audit Log data: https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs.html#jobs

(2) Newer System tables for auditing: https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/system-tables/audit-logs.html 

(3) Using the Databricks REST API (although this method would not be 100% SQL): https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/get

Comment: @ZachKing I've added more detail but it is repeating the same thing! I only need a query in sql language and not api calls. I will take a look at the newer system tables though! Not sure how audit logs would help, I will take a look at that as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Querying job properties from SQL is not currently possible in Databricks. However, there is a submission for this on the Databricks Ideas portal with many votes, and is now prioritized on the Databricks Roadmap: https://ideas.databricks.com/ideas/DBE-I-702

Apart from that, for now the only workarounds are:

1. Query access logs (part of the newer "System tables schemas" you can opt into) `SELECT request_params.new_settings FROM system.audit.access WHERE service_name = 'jobs' AND request_params.job_id = '<your_job_id>' AND request_params.new_settings IS NOT NULL ORDER BY event_time DESC LIMIT 1;`. https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/system-tables/audit-logs.html
2. Setup Account Audit Logs which provide a dedicated `jobs` table containing full event logs about all updates to jobs (similar to #1 but #1 is newer and much easier to setup). https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs.html#jobs